# Magento Export product Source model "magdoc/source_option" not found for attribute "magdoc_id"

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I'm exporting product but when I select product from drop down it gives me the below error:
**Source model "magdoc/source_option" not found for attribute "magdoc_id"**

When I select Customer from dropdown it show Entity attributes.

how can resolve this problem.

below is the error screenshot:
[image]

Comment: As it says ..do you have that model in your code base?

Comment: no. their no such model in my code

Comment: Then if you are not using that attribute then just delete it and go on. Otherwise use magento's default YES/NO option model.

Comment: where is the magento default YES/NO option model?

Comment: adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno ... But not sure if you want to use this. Decide yourself.

Comment: finally found the attribute in attribute management. after deleting the attribute it's showing product entity options. thanks Deb

Comment: you can post your comment as answer I'll accept that it helps others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you `are not using that attribute` then just `delete it` and go on. Otherwise use magento's default YES/NO option model. `adminhtml/system_config_source_yesno` ... But not sure if you want to use this. Decide yourself.